# Go build doesn't build custom libs

Tags: go, go-build

my working tree is like this:

```
/opt/go/src/tb-to-composer/
├── apis
│   └── rtb.go
├── config.yaml
├── jsondef
│   └── structures.go
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── tb-to-composer
└── thingsToComposer.go
```

when I do `go build` inside `/opt/go/src/tb-to-composer/` the build doesn't recompile `rtb.go` and `structures.go` even though there was changes in them. In order to achieve build I need to run `go build -a` every time I do a change to `rtb.go` or `structures.go`, is that the expected behavior from `go build`? How to I recompile only custom libs inside my package folder without recompile the whole `/opt/go/src` tree?

Comment: Is `thingsToComposer.go` your `main`, and does it reference the `apis` and `jsondef` packages? When you build in a directory, it builds only what it needs to in order to make that binary.

Comment: yes, thingsToComposer is my main imports tb-to-compose/apis and rtb.go imports tb-to-compose/jsondef

Answer (score 0):

You can try the -i flag, or (this does not work, sorry) specify the files in the directories explicitly as arguments to `go build`, i.e. `go build thingsToComposer.go apis/rtb.go jsondef/structures.go`

Comment: i've tried that:
`go build thingsToComposer.go apis/rtb.go jsondef/structures.go` returns
`named files must all be in one directory; have ./ and apis/`

and 
`go build ./thingsToComposer.go ./apis/rtb.go ./jsondef/structures.go`

same error

Comment: Sorry @viera, my fault. In my experience, when there are dependencies between my packages, all packages rebuild if dirty when I rebuild my main. Could you provide us with the import statements from your files?

Comment: of course! 
[thingsToComposer.go](https://gist.github.com/vieiramanoel/15e2edcb884e32bbf0b5af7a8d028270)
[rtb.go](https://gist.github.com/vieiramanoel/0c2c872b7a32ea7328b255f9d39fbf1b)

Comment: ok, so the package inside 'jsondefs' is named : `structures` - I would recommend having the package name be the same as the folder name. TBH, not sure if this is the source of the problem, though